# Error creating unit test with Spring cloud stream using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

i dunno how make one sample test using kafka, i tried to follow the spring guide but dont work.

Can someone help me?

zzzzz zz z z z z z z z z z z z

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext 
public class EnrollSenderTest {

@Autowired
public EnrollSender producer;

@Autowired
private BinderFactory<MessageChannel> binderFactory;

@Autowired
private MessageCollector messageCollector;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void test() {

    Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<>("hello");
    producer.sendEnroll(message);

    Message<String> received = (Message<String>) messageCollector.forChannel(producer.getOutput()).poll();
    assertThat(received.getPayload(), equalTo("hello"));
}
}
```

And my class Producer is:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class EnrollSender {

private final MessageChannel output;

public EnrollSender(Source output) {
    this.output = output.output();
}

public void sendEnroll(Object enroll) {
    output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(enroll).build());
}

public MessageChannel getOutput() {
    return output;
}
```

}

But gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCollector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/test/binder/TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollector]: Factory method 'messageCollector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderFactory.getBinder(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/Binder;

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollector]: Factory method 'messageCollector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderFactory.getBinder(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/Binder;

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderFactory.getBinder(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/Binder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a mismatched dependency set on the classpath (i.e. an older version of Spring Cloud Stream core).

You can solve this by removing the version for `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` because the `Camden.SR4` BOM will provide the correct one.

Moreover, if you want to test with an embedded Kafka instance, you can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multibinder/src/test/java/multibinder/RabbitAndKafkaBinderApplicationTests.java#L57

(The example shows you how to configure the Kafka binder with an embedded broker for testing - it also shows how to use two different binders within the same app, but probably you don't care about that).

Comment: `code` dependencyManagement {
 imports {
      mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR4"
   }
}

compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-stream-test-support', version: '1.1.1.RELEASE'

Answer (score 0):

Marius Bogoevici, my dependencys

```
dependencyManagement {
 imports {
      mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR4"
   }
}

compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-stream-test-support', version: '1.1.1.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the incompatible versions as pointed out by Marius above.

You would either need `Camden.SR5` that has compatible versions of Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Stream test support or `Camden.SR4` with Spring Cloud Stream test support version `1.1.0.RELEASE`.

[This](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/8ac71c7b57bc00b291e84ec345235be4ac57ba32#diff-6d5f3b1e84a8b2b367d41e47205784e9R32) is change that went in between `1.1.0.RELEASE` and `1.1.1.RELEASE` of Spring Cloud Steram:

Comment: revised Ilayaperumal Gopinathan thank you, I was able to add the second parameter, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Can you share your current dependencies and the exception stacktrace?